# creating ExtentReports instance throw NoSuchFieldError: VERSION_2_3_23 exception

Tags: java, report

I'm trying to create new instance of ExtentReports

```
if (extent == null) {
            extent = new ExtentReports(filePath, true);
```

and I got this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: VERSION_2_3_23
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.HTMLReporter.start(HTMLReporter.java:75)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.Report.attach(Report.java:302)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.<init>(ExtentReports.java:78)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.<init>(ExtentReports.java:362)
    at extentFadi.ex.ExtentManager.Instance(ExtentManager.java:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same freemarker version required by ExtentReports. Maybe you don't have the correct version.

Comment: Please add more details